# Does WP Super Cache really compress my pages?

Tags: optimization

I enabled the compression option on WP Super Cache (off by default!) on [my blog](http://ripper234.com/). After that, [Website Optimization](http://analyze.websiteoptimization.com/) started identifying my pages as being compressed (before, it didn't).

All seemed well with the world, but then I double checked with [Page Speed Firefox plugin](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/), and and sniffed the traffic with Wireshark, and according to both these measures my page is not compressed.

Are my pages being compressed or not? Could it be some proxy my ISP is running, that does not support compression? (that would explain some of the horrible internet experience I'm getting).

[Here](https://gist.github.com/938643) are the HTTP headers I'm seeing with wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting a `Content-Encoding:gzip` header when I visit your site...

```
Cache-Control:max-age=300, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sat, 23 Apr 2011 15:27:48 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:Identity
Vary:Accept-Encoding,Cookie
```

Also, you have a jQuery reference error in the wp-minify plugin :)

Comment: So the problem must be with my ISP (I tried from a different computer at my place, that one doesn't get gziped content as well). Crap. Well, I was switching ISP anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No WP Super Cache didn't compress the image to that level. Say around, it compress image to only 30% of its size. Means it is negligible Instead why not try for TinyPNG is works decently.